# referencing a knitr figure in text from lyx

Tags: knitr, lyx

I am using [lyx](/questions/tagged/lyx) to write an `rnw`file. In my `lyx` text, I would like to reference a figure generated by a [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr) code chunk that has label `"chunk1"`.

If I write the `rnw` in `Rstudio`, I would reference the figure by `\ref{fig:chunk1}` in my text. However in `lyx`, the label `"chunk1"` or `"fig:chunk1"` does not appear in the cross-Reference window.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Jing, welcome to SO. You should consider posting the code you used, it will be easier to understand what you did and where the mistakes are.

Comment: You can put `\ref{fig:chunk1}` in ERT in LyX

Comment: @scottkosty: Thank you very much for answering my question. The cross-reference works now. I needed to include \ref{fig:chunk1} in a TeX code box.

Comment: @J.Chomel Thank you. I'll learn to add code in my question. I love SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opinion about generating and cross-referencing knitr plots in LyX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940336/opinion-about-generating-and-cross-referencing-knitr-plots-in-lyx)