# Opinion about generating and cross-referencing knitr plots in LyX

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

I am aiming at including a knitr plot in LyX that I can cross-reference in my document.  I:

1. Inserted a float image.
2. Added a caption and a label.
3. Inserted a ERT instead of an image in the float image.

An image of what I did is here:

[image: Cross-refernce knitr figure in LyX]

I checked here at SO similar questions and nobody did what I've done so here I ask:

- Is there a simpler way to do what I am doing?
- How can I center the knitr image?

The code for my image is:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y1=rnorm(100)-1, y2=rnorm(100), y3=rnorm(100)+1) 
windows() 
plot(y1 ~ x, data=dat, type='n', axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")      
text(dat$x,dat$y1,label=round(runif(100,0,100),0),col='blue', cex = abs(rnorm(100,0,1)))
text(dat$x,dat$y2,label=round(runif(100,0,100),0),col='purple', cex = abs(rnorm(100,0,1)))
text(dat$x,dat$y3,label=round(runif(100,0,100),0),col='red', cex = abs(rnorm(100,0,1)))
@
```

Thanks for looking into this.  Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- How can I center the knitr image?

Alright, I figured out how to center the knitr image in a float image in LyX:

[image: Create a Float Image and caption it...]

Click on top of the caption and then right click to get Paragraph Settings so that you can center the ERT *before* inserting the ERT.

[image: Center the ERT]

Insert knitr chunk:
[image: Insert chunk]

You are done: the image is centered and it can be cross-referenced in your LyX file...

For the other question:

- Is there a simpler way to do what I am doing?

Perhaps there is but in LyX, by clicking on Help - Specific Manuals - Sweave, there is something similar to what I am doing as shown here:

[image: Sweave's Manual in LyX screenshot]

So I guess we're done with this...